# Линии с разным шагом на графике

Tags: excel, vba

Требуеться создать график с тремя линиями, при этом что бы третья линия имела иной шаг по отношению к остальным.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] К примеру задать положение 2 точки в пункте А

Даные загружаю в график с помощью кода:

```
With ActiveChart
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mass_graf_1
                .SeriesCollection(1).Type = xlLine
                .SeriesCollection(1).Name = Sheets("Score Performance Per Character").range("G" & count_total + 14).Value
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(2).Values = mass_graf_0
                .SeriesCollection(2).Type = xlLine
                .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                .SeriesCollection(3).Values = mass_graf_3
                .SeriesCollection(3).Type = xlLine
           End With
```

Где `mass_graf_0`, `mass_graf_1`, `mass_graf_3` одномерные массивы с положением точек.

Если использую `.xlValue` то шкала x изменяется для всех линий.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задать отдельную ось для ряда данных можно, но только вертикальную (*ПКМ на ряде данных-Формат_ряда_данных-параметры_ряда-По_вспомогательной_оси*).

С горизонтальной не получится. Но можно исключить точки, используя особенность диаграммы - умение игнорировать ошибки.

На любом листе записывается диапазон. В точках, которые показывать не нужно, создаем ошибку:

```
=НД()
```

Берем данные с листа и создаем графики:

```
Sub ChartLin()
Dim mass_graf_0(), mass_graf_1(), mass_graf_3()
    With Worksheets("temp")
        mass_graf_0 = .Range("A2:A12").Value
        mass_graf_1 = .Range("B2:B12").Value
        mass_graf_3 = .Range("C2:C12").Value
    End With

    With ActiveChart
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .SeriesCollection(1).Values = mass_graf_1
         .SeriesCollection(1).Type = xlLine
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .SeriesCollection(2).Values = mass_graf_0
         .SeriesCollection(2).Type = xlLine
         .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
         .SeriesCollection(3).Values = mass_graf_3
         .SeriesCollection(3).Type = xlLine
    End With
End Sub
```

Или одним махом загружается в диаграмму:

```
Sub ChartLine2()
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("A1:C12")
End Sub
```

Можно задать интервал между подписями  - 2 (в формате оси)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если вся обработка происходит в коде, то сначала формируем диапазон с ошибками на листе (записать ошибку в массив, не обращаясь к листу, не получилось)